# New cross platform mobile app places api

Tags: android, iphone, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm new to app development and have a few questions related to google maps and places

I am a USA resident and developing an application with a programmer in India which will work on Android and iPhone. I'm wondering if I can use apple maps on iPhone and run Google Places over it. I thought I read paper work saying google places must be run on google maps period. My programming guy said this is fine to do because my app will be free? And we will run google maps on iPhone after we have established people want the app? I will have to upgrade to the business edition of maps once the app hits say 10000 users also which means I can use places over any map.

Can anyone confirm this?

Thanks

James

Answer (score 1):

[Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/) usage must conform to our [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms). And yes, you are correct, you need to display Google Places API results on a Google Map. We have [Google Maps SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/) so that should be reasonably easy to accomplish.

Being a free app doesn't absolve you of conforming to our Terms of Service, fwiw.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Google Places API you can search the nearby places of a given co-ordinate. It is true that you can only request around 1000 times for free. Places API doesnt require you to be running any map application ( Apple Maps or Google Maps ). It is simply a WebService hosted by Google from which you get the data back. You can choose to display the data however you want.

Comment: Anyone else have any input? Thank you Abhishek